# computing frequencies in a nested list

Tags: python, list

I'm trying to compute the frequencies of words using a dictionary in a nested lists.  Each nested list is a sentence broken up into each word.  Also, I want to delete proper nouns and lower case words at the beginning of the sentence.  Is it even possible to get ride of proper nouns?

```
x = [["Hey", "Kyle","are", "you", "doing"],["I", "am", "doing", "fine"]["Kyle", "what", "time" "is", "it"]

from collections import Counter
def computeFrequencies(x):
    count = Counter()
    for listofWords in L:
        for word in L:
            count[word] += 1
    return count
```

It is returning an error: unhashable type: 'list'

I want to return exactly this without the Counter() around the dictionary:

```
{"hey": 1, "how": 1, "are": 1, "you": 1, "doing": 2, "i": , "am": 1, "fine": 1, "what": 1, "time": 1, "is": 1, "it": 1}
```

Comment: What is `L` in the loop?

Comment: accidentally x.  My bad for not changing it. @thefourtheye

Comment: It is hard to definitively eliminate proper nouns vs obscure words. For example, you could use a dictionary word list but 'kyle' is in the dictionary as 'a narrow sea channel.'

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Since your data is nested, you can flatten it with `chain.from_iterable` like this

```
from itertools import chain
from collections import Counter
print Counter(chain.from_iterable(x))
# Counter({'doing': 2, 'Kyle': 2, 'what': 1, 'timeis': 1, 'am': 1, 'Hey': 1, 'I': 1, 'are': 1, 'it': 1, 'you': 1, 'fine': 1})
```

If you want to use generator expression, then you can do

```
from collections import Counter
print Counter(item for items in x for item in items)
```

If you want to do this without using Counter, then you can use a normal dictionary like this

```
my_counter = {}
for line in x:
    for word in line:
        my_counter[word] = my_counter.get(word, 0) + 1
print my_counter
```

You can also use `collections.defaultdict`, like this

```
from collections import defaultdict
my_counter = defaultdict(int)
for line in x:
    for word in line:
        my_counter[word] += 1

print my_counter
```

Okay, if you simply want to convert the `Counter` object to a `dict` object (which I believe is not necessary at all since `Counter` is actually a dictionary. You can access key-values, iterate, delete update the `Counter` object just like a normal dictionary object), you can use [bsoist's suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23098468/computing-frequencies-in-a-nested-list/23098482?noredirect=1#comment35307265_23098482),

```
print dict(Counter(chain.from_iterable(x)))
```

Comment: how do I get rid of the Counter() around it? @thefourtheye

Comment: If you want a dict instead, you can also just do `dict(Counter(chain.from_iterable(x)))`

Comment: @bsoist I didnt understand what OP was asking. Thanks for clarifying :) I included that also in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, but actually, that's probably not exactly what he meant, so we should clarify that a Counter will behave like a dictionary and you can reference by key.

Comment: @bsoist I tried to explain a bit more. Please check.

Comment: I think it's a great answer. That's why I upvoted it - even before you mentioned me. :)

Comment: @bsoist Thanks. I am not a native English speaker, so I wanted to make sure that my answer reflects what I really mean :-)

Comment: :) and now that I reread the question too, that *is* what he OP was asking.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are iterating over `L` twice.

Replace the inner loop:

```
for word in L:
```

with:

```
for word in listofWords:
```

Though, if want to go "pythonic" - check out @thefourtheye's solution.

Comment: +1 I didnt know what `L` was. I left a comment in the question, but you figured it out already :)